# Quartz 2.x service does not start automatically

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, restart

I have Quartz.net running as a windows service. My problem is that the service does not start automatically (i.e. on Windows start).

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I have in the system event log:

"The Quartz Server service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to configure the jobstore to resolve the problem. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because of the wrong log4net version. My code used the newest version, while the quartz.net used an old version. So I replaced the old one with the newest one. So it crashed. 
Hope this help someone.